# Why can't I specify a margin on a root view?

Tags: xcode, uikit, xcode-storyboard

See here, there is no margin drop down...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Margins cannot be changed on the root view (even in code), so there is no point giving you a choice that would do nothing.

Comment: I apologize, but I've had to completely change my answer, as I learned something that I hadn't realized. Totally changing an accepted answer is rather rude, so I'm telling you about it in case this causes you to want to unaccept.